# How to call Post method with @Pathvariable annotation in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How should I call Post method with @PathVariable from browser?
Searched all the questions there is no straight answer for this question. Don't like to use other annotations.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PlugController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/command/{cmd}")
    public String command(@PathVariable(value = "cmd") String command) {
        return command;
    }

}
```

Calling from Browser like bellow:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/command/on
```

Error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.


There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
```

Comment: Did you encounter any issue when using `@PathVariable`

Comment: @KDFinal I did everything, but the method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `***Application` code or any logs, I use your code and it worked.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/command/{cmd}")
    public String command(@PathVariable(value = "cmd") String command) {
        return command;
    }
}
```

[image]

---update---

Use `@GetMapping` instand of `PostMapping` if you want request it via browser.

If you want to request a POST via browser, you need use javascript to create a form submit event, url as below:

**javascript** is requirement to let browser know this is a javascript.

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML='<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/api/command/aaa"></form>';document.forms[0].submit()})();
```

Notice that, there is no blank between **javascript:** and **(function()...**.

Comment: I checked it with Postman it is working, I was calling through browser. Why it is not working when I call it with browsers?

Comment: @Patzu, It's `GET` request through browser, so if you want use it through browser, you need use `GET` request and change `@PostMapping`  to `@GetMapping`

Comment: Why I cannot send post request from browser? What is the difference?

Comment: @Patzu, GET request is the default request in browser, GET request have no body and can be bookmarked by browser, you can see [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing this post request in postman. Our browers don't support post request due to several restrictions.